# Send HTTP response using C socket

Tags: c, http, sockets, response

I`m trying to send HTTP response to browser

```
char *reply = 
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
"Date: Thu, 19 Feb 2009 12:27:04 GMT\n"
"Server: Apache/2.2.3\n"
"Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Jun 2003 16:05:58 GMT\n"
"ETag: \"56d-9989200-1132c580\"\n"
"Content-Type: text/html\n"
"Content-Length: 15\n"
"Accept-Ranges: bytes\n"
"Connection: close\n"
"\n"
"sdfkjsdnbfkjbsf";

int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in addr;
bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(8081);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if(bind(sd,&addr,sizeof(addr))!=0)
{
    printf("bind error\n");
}

if (listen(sd, 16)!=0)
{
    printf("listen error\n");
}

for(;;)
{
    int size = sizeof(addr);
    int client = accept(sd, &addr, &size);

    if (client > 0)
    {
        printf("client connected\n");
        send(client, reply, sizeof(reply), 0);
    }
}
```

but my browser cant understand this, waits for a long time and then print smth strange. I guess my response is wrong, but I dont know how to fix. Any ideas?

Comment: should use strlen(reply), and add close(client)

Comment: maybe you also need a `\r` "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sizeof(reply)` evaluates to the size of a `char *`, aka size of a pointer. Use `strlen`.

```
send(client, reply, strlen(reply), 0);
```

Comment: Damn! Stupid mistake. Thanks!