# Apache Benchmark not continue after first request in a simple C server

Tags: c, http, benchmarking

I want to benchmark the "Hello World" performance of a HTTP server made in C. Despite the `curl -v http://localhost:8000/` gives an output and does not hang, Chrome does not open it an `ab -c 1 -n 10 http://localhost:8000/` makes the first request and does not continue after. I tried closing the client socket after sending data but it did not help. What is the cause of this?

I have used the code here: [Send HTTP response using C socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487297/send-http-response-using-c-socket)

Comment: try using \r\n line endings for http headers.

Comment: @chris still not working, it hangs on ab